# How do I use find-replace in Sublime Text 3 using shortcuts?

Tags: sublimetext3

On a Mac I can open find-replace with Cmd-Option-F:

[image]

But how do I execute the replacement using keyboard shortcuts? Hitting enter doesn't do it.

Comment: Replace/Replace All on the right?

Answer (score 1):

I think that You can use Replace or Replace All buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ctrl` + `h`. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/usage/search-and-replace.html#single-file) has the shortcuts listed for that.

`ctrl`+`shift`+`H` will replace the next occurrence.